# Adding to Sqlite Database While looping through ArrayList

Tags: android, sqlite, arraylist

i have a simple budget program that allows u to press a PayDay button that will increase the current amount in the budget by the amount set up when the budget was made. im having trouble getting the values out of the arraylist while still being able to acutually add them to the database this is what i have so far

```
        for(String amount: pds)
        {
            t2.put(KEY_AMOUNT, amount);
        }

        for(String Id: bIds)
        {
            t2.put(KEY_TRANSACTION,a);
            t2.put(KEY_DATE, date);
            t2.put(KEY_CATEGORYID, Id);
        }

        ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE2,null,t2);
        return ourDatabase;
```

all this does is put the last values in each list. i have tried several other ways but cant get it right
any and all help is greatly apreceated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that `t2` is a ContentValues object. They have a single value for each key, so setting the key 12 times just overwrites each time. You need to insert after every value if you want a different record for each value. If you want them to be joined into a CSV list or something, you need to use [TextUtils](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html) join method to concatenate the values. If you do that, make sure you are have your column type as `TEXT`.

Comment: thank you for your help i fixed it by chaging the for loop and inserting t2 before it runs through the loop again

Comment: if you want to make it faster, open a transaction before you start looping and end it after you are done with you database interaction. it doesn't make much difference if you are only making one or 2 database operations, but if you are looping through a bunch, it will save you a fair bit of time.